# Getting Video Analytic Information without Credentials

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I need to access several YouTube channels for my job to pull analytical data and export it to a database. The problem, is that this requires using OAuth, which would be fine except I don't know the controlling person's username/password. She probably won't give me her credentials since it's personal.

Is there a way to do this without explicitly using her username/pass? Like, she tried making me a content owner, but I still can't authorize this level of information.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason why OAuth was created, to make requests on behalf of a user without their username and password.

Have that user generate an access token.  Here are the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).  In a nutshell:

Have your user send a post request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` with your app key.  The response should look something like:

```
{
    type: "oauth",
    token: "XXXXXXX"
}
```

Then, make an API request on behalf of that user with their token by passing in the token returned from the previous step as value for the `Bearer` filed for any web request to the YouTube API.  This will allow you to perform an authenticated request without explicitly knowing the user's username and password.

Comment: The issue is getting the token. She gave me content owner rights, so now I can see all the channel IDs for the channels under her account. Is there a way I can see the channel data without authentication, if I am a content owner?

Comment: @NaomiDennis there is an `onBehalfOfContentOwner` parameter you can pass in to some requests, but I believe you're still required to be authenticated through OAuth **and** be a YouTube content partner.